# SSRS Desktop Report Builder Applicartion fails to Launch

Tags: reporting-services

Today when I start report builder from the start menu I see the splash screen then it closes.

I tried deleting temp files and files under "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0"

For testing I created a new local windows account and installed it again there and it launched fine.

Any ideas?

In the event viewer I found this:

```
Application: MSReportBuilder.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.

Exception Info: System.Xml.XmlException
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(System.Exception)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(System.Xml.XmlDocument, System.Xml.XmlReader, Boolean)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(System.Xml.XmlReader)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(System.String)
   at Microsoft.ReportDesigner.Properties.Settings+RBSettingsProvider.GetReader(System.String)
   at Microsoft.ReportDesigner.Properties.Settings+RBSettingsProvider.GetUserScopedReader()
   at Microsoft.ReportDesigner.Properties.Settings+RBSettingsProvider.GetPropertyValues(System.Configuration.SettingsContext, System.Configuration.SettingsPropertyCollection)
   at System.Configuration.SettingsBase.GetPropertiesFromProvider(System.Configuration.SettingsProvider)
   at System.Configuration.SettingsBase.GetPropertyValueByName(System.String)
   at System.Configuration.SettingsBase.get_Item(System.String)
   at System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.GetPropertyValue(System.String)
   at System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.get_Item(System.String)
   at Microsoft.ReportDesigner.Properties.Settings.get_RecentDataSources()
   at Microsoft.ReportDesigner.ApplicationSettings.get_Settings()
   at Microsoft.ReportDesigner.ReportDesigner.LoadAppConfigWndSize()
   at Microsoft.ReportDesigner.ReportDesigner..ctor()
   at Microsoft.ReportDesigner.ReportDesigner..ctor(Microsoft.ReportDesigner.AppArguments)
   at Microsoft.ReportDesigner.Program.Main(System.String[])
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this?  Report Builder stopped working for one of my users this week, with the exact same stack trace.  Last week it was working fine.  It is still working for me.

Comment: Yeah look under users home AppData/Local/Microsoft and try deleting or renaming "Report Builder" folder. Sometimes the app messes some preferences and then crashes. That worked for me (might be also localLow or roaming folders)

Comment: For me, the user's user.config file turned out to be 0 bytes, corrupted from earlier when the server had no disk space.  I ended up copying my user.config file overtop his and that fixed the issue.  The user.config file is in XML format which explains the System.Xml error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Yeah look under users home AppData/Local/Microsoft and try deleting or renaming "Report Builder" folder. Sometimes the app messes some preferences and then crashes. That worked for me (might be also localLow or roaming folders) – sproketboy Feb 25 at 22:11

The solution provided by sproketboy in their [comment on Feb 25 at 22:11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58768639/ssrs-desktop-report-builder-applicartion-fails-to-launch/61339336#comment106855491_58768639) worked for me. Given that it actually solved this situation for me, I'm re-posting it here as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

What fixed this for me was the user.config file in the local report builder folder was @ 0kb so I replaced it with another one off another computer and it works just fine now.